# Feedback for On Hold questions

Tags: feature-request

My question https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/383/what-evidence-is-there-of-an-anti-correlation-between-atlantic-basin-hurricanes remains on hold, despite it being modified in line with the feedback given and a request at the page for further feedback. It looks set to be closed soon. Given the lack of feedback to develop the question into a workable format, and lack of re-evaluation of the page following the suggested modifications, is there a point of putting pages on hold, rather than just closing them?

Answer (score 2):

You need to realize that since we moved to Public beta we are very few to have close votes and reopen votes privileges. You need to let people some time to act on it.

As for your specific question, i think it's mostly a problem of legibility, i suggested an edit, to turn it into an actual question. I also voted to reopen as indeed it is now an answerable question and not just a quote as it was before.

Additionally "on hold" and "closed" are basically the same thing. "Deleted" is something else, that comes later, if indeed the question was unsalvageable, which was not.

Usually, when an edit is made to a question put "on hold", it should appear in the "Reopen" review queue, where people see the edit and can judge if it is sufficient to get reopen. I checked in my review history and didn't see your question in it. So I don't know what happened, if people decided to leave it closed before i saw it or if it didn't make it to the queue.

Otherwise, people who closed the question are not "pinged" when you edit or comment on the question, meaning we have to remember to check on it frequently if we want to give feedback.

Now if you think they should be a real, quickest feedback mechanism, you should bring the issue on [Meta StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) as this is the proper place to suggest new features network-wide.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I did try and escalate it in the right way, waiting for a response to the edit (24h), request information in the post(48h) (perhaps this should have used @usernames in hindsight), I then contacted the help system (72h)(which I guess is not really operating, while there are no interim mods) then finally post here (96h).

Comment: I guess now you just have to wait for the people in UTC-5 and further west to wake-up and join in since the post is still a few reopen votes short.